# How can i reduce the size of a table with filestream

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I am working on a database function which activate filestream for a couple of tables.

It seems to work just fine. Filestream on SQL Server is enabled, the database has it enabled too.

I can now either create a new table with filestream columns, or I can add a column with filestream.

Both options seem to work.

Files are created in the FS directory.

The problem for me now is the table size.

- When I create a new table and insert/copy data into it, the size of the table is (for example) under 1 MB
- When I add a new column to the existing table and copy the data over, the table size is over 10 MB

Here is what I used to enable FS on the table and copy the data:

```
EXEC sys.sp_rename
    @objname = N'dbo.tImage.bImage', 
    @newname = bImage_OLD, 
    @objtype = 'COLUMN' 

ALTER TABLE dbo.tImage ADD bImage VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL

UPDATE dbo.tImage
SET bImage = bImage_OLD

ALTER TABLE dbo.tImage DROP COLUMN Image_OLD
```

How can I reduce the size of the table after I added the new column, or is this even possible without creating a new table?

I already tried to shrink the database file and the transaction log.
I also performed a `DBCC CHECKDB REPAIR_REBUILD`.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(2)
DBCC SHRINKFILE(2, EMPTYFILE) 
DBCC CLEANTABLE(myDB, 'dbo.tImage')
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

The most documentation I found mentioned a new database and inserting new rows.

I also found a blog post that describes my preferred way to copy the data here.

[sqlshack.com](https://www.sqlshack.com/working-with-sql-server-filestream-adding-columns-and-moving-databases/)

**UPDATE:**

When I add a new picture to my changed table, the Size of the table does not increase. In this case it is a semi success for me, but I want the initial table size to be small as possible, and I know there is potential.

Using the following Code seem to fix my problem. I tried it before already, but with using the Schema and get some other problems. I have to investigate it more.

```
DBCC CLEANTABLE(database, 'tImage')
```

Comment: Does it help to rebuild the clustered index on the table? Adding columns at the end is not same as creating table as is from scratch, since data needs to be re-arranged much more in the first case.

Comment: @siggemannen that's a good hint but unfortunate to me, rebuild the index does not help

Comment: How exactly is this filestream related? Filestream is only applicable to `varbinary(max)` columns decorated with the `filestream` attribute. The original `bImage` column was `nvarchar(1035)` according to your notes, and the new `bImage` column is only `varbinary(max)` without the `filestream` attribute.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning oh, damn, that's an old comment and the code example is the other way around, to remove the FS, copied the wrong part of the script, I updated it now

At first, rename the old image column, then add the new FS-column, update it and delete the old column.
Alternative to this i created a whole new table and inserted the data, this worked for me just fine, but i do not want to create a new table.

Comment: I think, i fix it, I have to spend more investigation on this.  I just use `DBCC CLEANTABLE(DB,TABLE)`